# No response from POST request Spring boot - AJAX

Tags: ajax, spring-boot, post, request

I try to send data from AJAX POST request and don't get an answer, but if I send the exact same request with POSTMAN I *do* get a response. I don't know what is causing this.

REST Spring boot:

```
@RestController
public class UsuarioRest {
UsuarioController usuarioController = new UsuarioController();
String token = null;
Usuario usuario = null;

@GetMapping(value = "/hola")
public ResponseEntity<?> login(@RequestBody Usuario user) {
    token = usuarioController.login(user.getUser(), user.getPassword());
    if (token != null) {
        usuario = new Usuario(user.getUser(), user.getPassword());
        usuario.setToken();
        return new ResponseEntity<Usuario>(usuario, HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
        return new ResponseEntity<Error>(new Error(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

AJAX POST:

```
$(document).ready(
function() {

    // SUBMIT FORM
    $("#btnEnviar").submit(function(event) {
        // Prevent the form from submitting via the browser.
        event.preventDefault();
        ajaxPost();
    });

    function ajaxPost() {

        // PREPARE FORM DATA
        var User = {
            id:0,
            user : $("#user").val(),
            password : $("#password").val(),
            token:0
        }

        console.log(formData);
        // DO POST
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            contentType : "application/json",
            url : "hola",
            data : JSON.stringify(User),
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(result) {
                console.log(result);
                if (result.status == "success") {
                    $("#resultado").html(
                        "" + result.data.token
                        + "Post Successfully! <br>"
                        + "---> Congrats !!" + "</p>");
                } else {
                console.log(result);
                    $("#resultado").html("<strong>Error</strong>");
                }
            },
            error : function(e) {
                alert("Error!")
                console.log("ERROR: ", e);
            }
        });

    }

})
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<form id="login">
<input type="text" id="user">
<input type="text" id="password">
<button type="submit" id="btnEnviar" >Enviar</button>
</form>
<div id="resultado">
<button id="hola"></button>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Should `type : "GET"` not be `type : "POST"`?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. I didnt realize, I was just trying another alternative when I published this code but I tried with POST with no result.

Comment: check  whether the request has been made on network or trying postman to do a request

Comment: The request is not present in the network on the console but when I do a request in POSTMAN it works